# Long Put -- Can't execute

Tags: put-options, option-exercise, options-assignment

I'd like to buy a so-called "naked" put option on VTI.  In order to exercise the put if the price of VTI is at the strike price or below, I must find someone to buy it at the strike price.  I realize that the person who sold the put to me, or someone else who sold an identical put, is legally required to buy at the strike price, and will be assigned.  But what happens if they don't have the means to meet their obligation?  True, their broker will ideally make sure that they have sufficient assets in their account, but things happen.  Are people ever not able to exercise their short puts for this reason? Do they ever get stuck with their puts?

Comment: I don't understand your question. People get stuck with long puts all the time, just like with long calls. You bought a put, so that gives you the right but not the obligation to sell stock at the put's strike price. If the put expires worthless, then you are out whatever you paid for the put (the premium) but no more than that. Someone who is short a put would have a margin account, and once their losses on the put exceeded however much they were allowed by their broker, the brokerage would close out the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'll try to express this more clearly and simply. Mike sells me a single put contract with VTI as the underlying security, at a strike price of X. I now have a right to sell Mike 100 shares of VTI at the strike price. Suppose the market price of VTI falls below the strike price and I try to sell the shares. Mike technically has an obligation to buy them.  My question is how often -- if ever -- does it occur that Mike doesn't have the means, even considering his margin. Maybe his margin was closed out due to other investments, for example.

Comment: @Ellie Kesselman - The OP isn't talking about his long put expiring worthless.  He asked about the scenario where his long put is in-the-money and he wants to exercise it.

Answer (score 2):

Decades ago, traders used the terminology of buying a naked put.  Today, a 'naked put' means selling a put option by itself (uncovered) without any offsetting positions. The counterparty to that trade simply buys a long put.

When you want to sell your long put, you don't have to 'find someone to buy it at the strike price'. The market maker is required to provide liquidity.  You may not like the price but there will be a price available.  If it's an active option, other traders may be the market.

These days, brokers actively monitor margin and risk and blowing out an account is isn't a frequent event.  In the unlikely event that happens, the Options Clearing Corporation (OCC) acts as a guarantor to ensure that the obligations of option contracts are fulfilled.

Comment: Super useful answer!   I looked up the OCC and did confirm that it serves the guarantor function that you described.   -- Just an aside.  I looked up "naked put", and by far the results were consistent with what you said, i.e., that it is selling an uncovered put option.  However, I did find a few that were consistent with my description, which is buying a put without also holding shares of the security underlying that put, i.e., a put that's not a protected put.